# Compare content of excel by using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to read two list of content from two excel file. The reading is success and I want to compare the differences of these two lists. I use in_array() function to check if the item that I am checking is exist in the other list. Some of them can be checked some of them cannot even this item exist.

```
//check if string(18) "Multimedia library" ==> ASCII exist in the array below
// as you can see it should be matched at index 0

array(8) { [0]=> string(18) "Multimedia Library" 
[1]=> string(17) "Reference Library" 
[2]=> string(17) "Basic Law Library" 
[3]=> string(41) "Creativity and Innovation Resource Centre" 
[4]=> string(29) "Business and Industry Library" 
[5]=> string(35) "Web-based Education Resource Centre" 
[6]=> string(30) "Sports and Fitness Information" 
[7]=> string(0) "" } 

//encoding of each item in the array above
string(18) "Multimedia Library" ==> ASCII
string(17) "Reference Library" ==> ASCII
string(17) "Basic Law Library" ==> ASCII
string(41) "Creativity and Innovation Resource Centre" ==> ASCII
string(29) "Business and Industry Library" ==> ASCII
string(35) "Web-based Education Resource Centre" ==> ASCII
string(30) "Sports and Fitness Information" ==> ASCII
string(0) "" ==> ASCII
```

I have checked the encoding of each item that read from the excel and cannot found any different. However, the "Multimedia Library" could not been found in the array above. Could you please any possible reason?

Comment: How about sharing your code?